# React.js: Child input defaultValue after update is correct in HTML, but not displaying correctly on the page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-component

In `App`, I have a child component that has a child component which contains an `<input>`, and another child component which contains an `<input>`. The structure is as follows:

```
<App>
  <Parent>
    <ClassWithInput1 />
  </Parent>
  <ClassWithInput2 />
</App>
```

In `App.state`, I have a string `val` that can be set through either of the `<input>` fields, and is displayed using the `defaultValue` attribute in both `<input>` fields when it is updated.

When it is updated with `ClassWithInput1`, the value for the `<input>` in `ClassWithInput2` is updated correctly. However, when I update it in `ClassWithInput2`, the changes are not reflected in `ClassWithInput1`. `App.state.val` is being updated correctly in both cases. I checked in the Chrome inspector, and the `value` attribute in the HTML is correct in `ClassWithInput1`, but the actual changes aren't displayed on the page.

Here is a sandbox example of the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-thunder-z1p81?file=/src/App.js.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refactor your input to each have a local state to handle its input value. at `componentDidUpdate` you check if `this.props.val` is a new value:

Input.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Input1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    };
  }

  handleKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.inputRef.current.blur();
    }
  };

  handleBlur = e => {
    this.props.setVal(this.state.inputValue);
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProp) {
    if (prevProp.val === this.props.val) return
    // it will update input value for other input change
    this.setState({ inputValue: this.props.val })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          spellCheck="false"
          // use value instead of DefaultValue
          value={this.state.inputValue}
          ref={this.inputRef}
          onKeyDown={e => this.handleKeyPress(e)}
          onBlur={e => this.handleBlur(e)}
          // add a onChange handler to update state
          onChange={ e => this.setState({inputValue : e.target.value}) }
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any reason as to why setting it as ```this.props.val``` directly doesn't work?

Comment: because `defaultValue` is only the initial value for no changes at input. likewise if you set `this.props.val` directly at `value` it will block input change to an empty string (which is props.val initial value). you need a state and a onChange handler to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer!